# If $30\mid p_1^4 + p_2^4 + \ldots + p_{31}^4$ then $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$ and $p_3=5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p_1 < p_2 < . . . < p_{31}$ be prime numbers such that $30$ divides
> $p_1⁴ + p_2⁴+ · · · + p_{31}⁴$. Prove that $p_1 = 2$, $p_2 = 3$ and $p_3 = 5$.

We know that $30$ divides the sum of the fourth powers of the $31$ prime numbers, so $30$ must also divide the sum of their residues modulo $30$. Specifically, we have:

$p_1^4 + p_2^4 + ... + p_{31}^4 ≡ 0 (mod 30)$

Now, we can observe that for any prime number $p$, $p^4 ≡ 1 (mod 30)$ if $p$ is coprime to $30$. This can be seen by considering the possible residues of $p$ modulo $30$ and noting that $p^4$ is always $1$ modulo $2$ and $1$, $4$, or $16$ modulo $3$. Therefore, we have:

$p_1^4 + p_2^4 + ... + p_{31}^4 ≡ r_1 + r_2 + ... + r_{31} (mod 30)$

where $r_i$ is the residue of $p_i^4 modulo 30$.

Now how to approach.. please help.. thank you...

Comment: If $p^4$ were always equivalent to $1 (mod 2)$, could that sum ever be equivalent to $0 (mod 30)$?

Comment: "$p^4$ is always $1$ modulo $2$ and $1$, $4$, or $16$ modulo $3$" should be replaced with "$p^4$ is always $1$ modulo $2,$ $3,$ and $5.$ (You forgot $\bmod5,$ and you repeated thrice the same residue $\bmod3$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it one by one.

Start from modulo 2. If $p\equiv 1 (mod2)$, then $p^4 \equiv1 (mod2)$. So, if all $p_i \equiv 1(mod2)$, then $p_1^4 + \cdots + p_{31}^4 \equiv 31 \equiv 1 (mod 2)$. This is a contradiction. So there must be at least one $p_i\equiv 0(mod 2)$. Thus $p_1 = 2$.

The same argument applies for modulo 3 since $p \equiv 1,2 (mod 3)$ implies $p^4\equiv 1$. So, if all $p_i \equiv 1,2(mod3)$, then $p_1^4 + \cdots + p_{31}^4 \equiv 31 \equiv 1 (mod 3)$. This is a contradiction. So there must be at least one $p_i\equiv 0(mod 3)$. Since we already have $p_1=2$, we conclude $p_2 = 3$.

The same argument applies for modulo 5 since $p \equiv 1, 2, 3, 4 (mod 5)$ implies $p^4\equiv 1$. So, if all $p_i \equiv 1, 2, 3, 4 (mod5)$, then $p_1^4 + \cdots + p_{31}^4 \equiv 31 \equiv 1 (mod 5)$. This is a contradiction. So there must be at least one $p_i\equiv 0(mod 5)$. Since we already have $p_1=2, p_2=3$, we conclude $p_3 = 5$.

Comment: A prime $p\ne3$ is not necessarily $\equiv1\bmod3.$ Same for $5.$

Comment: @AnneBauval It was typos! Thanks! Just fixed them.

Comment: There are residual mistaken $\equiv1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks again!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).